# What does it take to become a "research engineer" in computer engineering?

Tags: education, title, job-description, software

I recently discovered that research engineer in computer science seems interesting and relevant both for academia and corporations. Now I wonder if I must have a Ph D in computer science to become a "research engineer" or could anyone become a "research engineer"?

I'm five courses short of a BS in computer engineering and I have several years of professional software development experience. I'm entitled "IT consultant", "IT specialist", "computer programmer", "software engineer", "system development consultant" in my recent positions.

I'm interested and motivated about the subject and I want to know if I must pursue a higher education than BS computer science and engineering to apply for a research engineer position, and I want to learn more about what that position is.

Comment: We specifically don't give career advice on Workplace SE. Maybe someone will give you some good pointers before the question is closed, but it is unfortunately out of scope.

Comment: "I wonder if I must have a Ph D in computer science to become a 'research engineer'" - This part is almost certainly company specific. Of all companies that have an open position with the title "research engineer", some may require you have a Ph.D. in computer science, and others may not require that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the company, but at the *very* few companies which stull have a real research division this is essentially equivalent to being a continuous PhD candidate/untenured academic researcher. You need to be able to continually generate new and interesting ideas which stretch the field in directions which are useful/interesting to your employer. It is very much a publish-or-perish environment, where the best are rewarded and the lowest ranked are pushed back in the direction of more immediate product development.

Most of the industry can't afford (relatively) pure research, and combines it into Development as R&D.

So, yes, true Research is one of the areas where advanced degrees may actually be useful outside academia. You need to know a field pretty well to spot the interesting areas that haven't been adequately explored.

(I've worked in the Research Division, but as support staff rather than as a Research Staff Member. I think if my career had gone differently I might have been able to operate at that level, but I may never know.)